# Flutter Package > Text file access > PathNotFoundException

Tags: flutter, dart, package

Following is revised working code in both package and application.

Prior to changing the path to include packages i was getting PathNotFoundException

This works where:

1. rootBundle.loadString is called
2. packages path == 'packages/tester/assets/data.csv'
3. package pubspec.yaml has

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/data.csv
```

4. ensure package is reloaded within application if you make changes
5. tests work in both package and application!

Also see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/65921a

### Flutter Package > tester

I have created a flutter package tester.
tester package accesses a file in the assets directory, directly under the package root directory:

- tester/assets/data.csv

pubspec.yaml contains:

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/data.csv
```

When i test the package its works fine.

### Application Test

When i test the package in an application it fails with PathNotFoundException

where the package location is:

- applicationroot/packages/tester/assets/data.csv

pubspec.yaml contains:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  macservice:
    path: packages/tester
```

### Package Class

```
class Service{
    Future<void> loadData() async {
      -  var lines = await File('assets/data.csv').readAsLines();

      + var filestring = await rootBundle.loadString('packages/tester/assets/data.csv');
      + var lines = filestring.split('\n');

        for (var line in lines) {
            var fields = line.split(',');
            if (fields.length == 2) {
                print('${fields[0]}: ${fields[0]}');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Package Test Code > Works

```
void main() {
    setUp(()  {
        WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    });
    test('load data', () async {
        final service = Service();
        var data = await service.loadData();
    });
}
```

### Application Test Code

```
void main() {
    group('A group of tests', () {
        Service service;

    setUp(()  {
        WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    });
  
    test('load data', () async  {        
        service = new Service();
        var data = await service.loadData();
    });
  });
}
```